# Javascript: search autocomplete - fetch results from mysql database?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, search

I am trying to achieve a search bar on my website that shows a list of suggestive search results as a user types them in.

So if someone starts to type in `Hew`

and the value `Hewden` exists in my database then this will show up in the suggestive search results drop down list

I have the following html form setup on my page search.php:

**search.php**

```
<form action="include/search_source.php" method="post" name="searchForm">
<input type="text" name="search" class="Search_bar_box" id="search" autocomplete="off">
</form>


<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#search').autocomplete({source:'include/search_source.php', minLength:2, select: function (event, ui) {
            window.location = 'search_results.php?search=' + ui.item.value;

        }});

    $('#searchForm').on("submit", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert($('#search').val());
    });

});


</script>
```

In search_source.php i have the following code which runs a mysql query which is suppose to lookup my values from the database:

**search_source.php:**

```
<?php
include 'config.php';

$rs = mysql_query('select * from supplier_stats where company_name like "'. mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['term']) .'%" OR supplier_number like "'. mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['term']) .'%" OR descrip like "'. mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['term']) .'%" order by company_name asc limit 0,5');

// loop through each zipcode returned and format the response for jQuery
$data = array();
if ( $rs && mysql_num_rows($rs) )
{
    while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($rs, MYSQL_ASSOC) )
    {
        $data[] = array(
            'label' => $row['company_name'] .' - '. $row['supplier_number'] .' - '. $row['descrip'] ,
            'value' => $row['company_name']
        );
    }
}

// jQuery wants JSON data
echo json_encode($data);
flush();

?>
```

I am then including **search.php** in my page **dashboard.php** like so:

```
<?php include 'search.php'; ?>
```

For some reason this code works on my local host server but doesn't work on my main server. can someone please show me what i am doing wrong? or perhaps show me a better way of doing this? Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the error message ?

Comment: @ClémentPrévost there isnt one

Comment: Have you checked the webserver logs, the system logs, the console output and the php logs ?

Comment: Add <?php ini_set('display_errors',1); ?> as the first line of your PHP file so you can see the error message.  It is probably a database issue.